# Issues with putting Charts on Groups

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am trying to get a Chart to work in the Header for a Group in Telerik Reports.  I am using a pie chart, and I am using the DataGroupColumn property.  The code is below

```
        Me.Chart1.DataGroupColumn = "Mfg"
        ChartSeries1.DataYColumn = "Quantity"
        ChartSeries1.Type = Telerik.Reporting.Charting.ChartSeriesType.Pie
```

And my data is as follows

```
Mfg  Model              ProductNumber         Qty
HP   LaserJet 4700      a3482-3938-2259       32
Dell Laser 1710n        72C8FMC               15
HP   Bubble Jet 3320    d339-2938-2923        27
Dell Laser 1100         72C8FMC               15
HP   LaserJet 4700      12952-7342-3567       32
Dell Laser 1710n        68923C9               15
```

And in my report, I have a group for Mfg, then a group for Model.  I tried putting the Chart in the Header for the Mfg group, but the chart only shows the data for the very first group.  Is there a way to get the chart to display the data for the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, I guess the only way to do it is manually... BOOOOOOO!

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/reporting/telerik-reporting/graph-for-each-group.aspx